# The Contributor permission group got deleted. How I create a new one?

Tags: azure-devops

I have an azure devops project in which the contributor permission group got deleted. Their seems to be implicit permissions on that group that you can't add to other groups. I tried making a new group with the same name but the permissions such as viewing the board are still not working.
Is there anyway to fix/restore the built-in group?

Answer (score 1):

By default, the team group created when you create a project is added to Contributors group, and any user you add to the team or project is a member of this group. In addition, any team you create for a project is added to this group.

After you create Contributors group and set the permission properly, you also need to add the users and team group to this group.

Comment: So you are saying as long as re-create a new group with the name Contributors it will take the place of the old built-in one? Because the built in groups: Contributors, Reader, and Project Admins seem to have permissions that you can't set in the UI. Like viewing the board is not a permission I can set access to in the UI.

Comment: If you mean the user can not access boards, you could check whether they can access the area path: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/security/set-permissions-access-work-tracking?view=azure-devops#create-child-nodes-modify-work-items-under-an-area-path

Comment: I mean all this permissions attached to the built-in Contributors group are not settable when you create new group. there is only 21 permissions listed on the permission tab and none are the ones listed in this link. I see the security settings on the board you mention and found same in the pipline section but how to I make sure all permissions get exactly the way the built-in Contributiors group was? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/get-started/permissions-access-boards?view=azure-devops

Comment: I'm afraid you have to add the group manually to each permission you need. It's not able to restore a group automatically.